ReferenceError: Rails is not defined when importing @rails/ujs in Rails 7
I'm new on using Ruby on Rails and I'm a bit confused on how to import @rails/ujs. This is my app/javascript/application.js code:
import Rails from "@rails/ujs";
import Turbolinks from "turbolinks";
import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage";
import "channels";
import "bootstrap";
import "controllers";

Rails.start();
Turbolinks.start();
ActiveStorage.start();

Also, this is my importmap.rb code
pin "@rails/ujs", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@rails/ujs@7.0.4/lib/assets/compiled/rails-ujs.js"
pin "turbolinks", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:turbolinks@5.2.0/dist/turbolinks.js"
pin "@rails/activestorage", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@rails/activestorage@7.0.4/app/assets/javascripts/activestorage.esm.js"
pin "bootstrap", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
pin_all_from "app/javascript/channels", under: "channels"
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"


As I suspected, @rails/ujs is not being correctly imported, so I checked "Rails" in the console and it came up with the ReferenceError.
Is there anything wrong with those? I've been trying a lot to fix it, but nothing is working. If there's any other code you'd like to check before answering please let me know.
I tried restarting the server, using bundle install and using other syntaxes for the app/javascript/application.js code.

don't use @rails/ujs and turbolinks, these libraries are dead and have been replaced by turbo in rails 7. find yourself an upto date tutorial, because it looks like you're using rails 6 setup for rails 7. not to mention, we're weeks away from a stable rails 8 release.
